# How to solve "Error message 'where' operator in UrlClickEvents" error?

Tags: kql

Error message:

> 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'UrlClickEvents'

Tried this "Kusto Query Language (KQL)" query in Defender Advanced hunt and goal is i want to see when the URL is clicked. But, occurred above error. How to solve this?.

Query:

```
UrlClickEvents
| where ActionType == "ClickAllowed" or IsClickedThrough !="0"
| where ThreatTypes has "Phish"
| summarize by ReportId, IsClickedThrough, AccountUpn, NetworkMessageId, ThreatTypes, Timestamp
```

"Defender advanced hunt query"

Comment: Table *UrlClickEvents* does not exist (please note that KQL is case sensitive)

Comment: Please add the relevant tags for the service you are using